# How can I trigger validation onblur with CanJS?

Tags: javascript, validation, canjs, canjs-model

I have a Can JS model with an `init` that runs `this.validateNonBlank("title");`. How can I trigger that validation to run `onblur`, when I tab out of the `title` field? Right now it only triggers when another element triggers the `change` event.

```
can.Model.Cacheable("CMS.Models.Program", {
  root_object : "program"
  , root_collection : "programs"
  ...
  , links_to : {
    "Regulation" : "ProgramDirective"
    , "Policy" : "ProgramDirective"
    ...
    , "Market" : {}
  }
  , init : function() {
    var that = this;
    this.validateNonBlank("title");
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);
  }
}, {
});
```

(The full code is [here](https://github.com/reciprocity/ggrc-core/blob/develop/src/ggrc/assets/javascripts/models/simple_models.js).)

Comment: Could you include a minimal code example including HTML? An event like onblur would require interactions with the DOM, which shouldn't be handled by a Model on its own.